# Is open ball in two dimensions a disk?

Tags: metric-spaces

I got some trouble with this problem:

Prove that a set $\{(x,y)|x>0\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

My idea is to consider the open ball $B_r((a,b))$ with r=a/2 and (a,b) is a point in the set.

But I am not sure if $B_r((a,b))$ should be expressed by $(x-a)^2$+$(y-b)^2$< $r^2$

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by (a,b), open ball should only take one point as it's center

Comment: @YujieZha $(a,b)$ is a point in $R^2$

Comment: $B_r((a,b))$ is the set of points less than distance $r$ from $(a,b)$. If your distance function is $d((x,y),(a,b))=\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}$, then this set is indeed those points $(x,y)$ which satisfy $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2<r^2$.

Comment: @ThePortakal Ah, Ok, I was expecting for one point, and did not realized that you used (a,b) to represent a point. Thanks for editing, you are right as you mentioned in your question, it is a disk. And you just need to show that for each point of the set, there exists an open ball that's contained within the set.

Comment: @YujieZha it's not my question though

Comment: @ThePortakal So what your question? "you are right as you mentioned in your question, it is a disk" - from my previous comment. Or did you ask for how to prove that ? Do you need to expand it into that formula in order to prove it? If that is your question, I do not think you need to.

Comment: @YujieZha haha, I did not asked the question, I am __not__ the OP :)

Comment: @ThePortakal ha, gotcha. Was reading over my phone, did not realize that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I was taught with the notation $B_{\mathbb{R^2}}(x,\epsilon)$, which is an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ around $x$ of radius $\epsilon$. Just thought I'd let you know in case you ever come across it!

The set $\{(x,y) | x>0\}$ consists of both quadrants I and IV (discluding the $y$-axis). So, I believe you're on the right track. You want to consider the open ball $B_r(a,b)$ (using your notation), where $(a,b)$ is a point in the set and $r=\frac{a}{2}$. So, every point in this open ball has $x$-coordinate strictly greater than $\frac{a}{2}$, which is a positive number since $a$ is positive. This implies the ball is entirely contained in quadrants I and IV (in other words, our initial set).